# How to make Roles mandatory in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger, configuration, customization

I had a curious question, **can we make role mandatory in salesforce?**
Is it possible, and if yes, how to achieve that?

I'm thinking of writing a before insert trigger on User object, will it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation Rule on `User`

```
ISBLANK(UserRole) /* UserRole is required */
```

Of course the rule can be more sophisticated to cater for different profiles or custom permissions

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this simply by validation rule. You don't need to write code for this.

Always avoid writing code if the solution can be achieved by some configuration.